# how can I fix my problem for reducing my excel data with correlation in python?TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, correlation

```
data_a = pd.read_excel("D://thesis//LapGyn4_v1.0//Surgical_Actions//mydata2.xlsx")
data_a
cols1 = data_a.columns
corrList = []
labels = data_a.iloc[:,1200]
a1 = np.corrcoef(data_a.iloc[:,0], labels)
print(a1[0,1])
for i in range(data_a.shape[1]):
    a1 = np.corrcoef(data_a.iloc[:,i], labels)
    corrList.append(a1[0,1])
a1 = range((1200))
lists = [a1,corrList]
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(x) for x in lists], axis=1)
df.iloc[:,1] = abs(df.iloc[:,1])
df2 = df[df.iloc[:,1]>0.18]
print(df2.shape)
df2.iloc[(df2.shape[0]-1),0] = 1200
allData3 = data_a.iloc[:,df2.iloc[:,0].astype(int)]
allData3.to_csv('D://thesis//LapGyn4_v1.0//Surgical_Actions//reduceddata2.csv',index=False)
```

this is my code and I have this error for this problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BjvN.png)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

how can I fix it?
I want to have feature reduction by using correlation with this code but I receive this error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @barmar can you help me?